# Prove a Generalized Hypergeometric Function Identity of $_4F_3$

Tags: combinatorics, hypergeometric-function

Let $k$ be a non-negative integer and $s$ a complex number. I am trying to prove the identity
$$
\;_4F_3\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{k}{2} & -\frac{k}{2} & \frac{k}{2}+\frac{s}{2} \\
&\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{2} & 1+\frac{k}{2} & 1-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{s}{2} 
\end{array};1 \right)=\frac{B(s,s)2^{k-1+s}}{\binom{2k}{k}B(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{s}{2}-\frac{k}{2},\frac{s}{2}+\frac{k}{2})}+\frac{1}{2}
$$
Mathematica verifies some special cases, but the general result remains a conjecture.

Comment: Might it be OK to assume $0<\text{Re}(s)<1$? That would really simplify the casework in defining $_4F_3$...